# Modifying JQuery to reset function

Tags: jquery

A member by the name of ocanal was nice enough to help me write a JQuery function (you can view the jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/JMqxq/5/), but I now want to modify it. I was able to successfully modify it so that when you correctly guess a color, the 'level' increments by one and displays it correctly. What I'm having trouble with, is having it kind of 'reset' so that once you guess the correct color, the previous incorrect boxes are no longer faded out and the random number generator has selected a new correct color for you to guess. Any idea how I can do this? Here is a the particular function I would like to modify:

```
temp = Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1);
  $("div.box").click(function() {
      if (temp == $(this).data("id")) {
          correct();
      } else {
          $(this).animate({"opacity": "0.25"}, "slow");
          incorrect();
      }
  });
```

Also here is the function that is called when there is a correct guess if you need that:

```
 function correct(){
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You are correct!";
  level++;
  document.getElementById("level").innerHTML = level;
 }
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `correct` function you need to animate each box back to an opacity of 1, like this:

```
$(".box").animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
```

The function is then:

```
function correct(){
  $("#result").html("You are correct!");
    level++;
  $(".box").animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
  document.getElementById("level").innerHTML = level;
}
```

I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JMqxq/6/).

Comment: Thanks! The correct guess isn't changing though. Should I just copy and past "temp = Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1);" into correct()? Or is there a better way than that?

Comment: You would be better calling rand() at the end of the correct function I think.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at jsFiddle the updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JMqxq/9/).

I made a change, added a reset() function and called it after the correct() function call.

```
window.onload = init;
var temp = 0;
var level = 1;
function init(){
  rand();
 }

function rand(){
  temp = Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1);
  $("div.box").click(function() {
      if (temp == $(this).data("id")) {
          correct();
          reset();
      } else {
          $(this).animate({"opacity": "0.25"}, "slow");
          incorrect();
      }
  });
}

function reset(){
    $(".box").each( function () {
        $(this).animate({"opacity": "1.0"}, "slow");
    });
}

function correct(){
  $("#result").html("You are correct!");
    level++;
  document.getElementById("level").innerHTML = level;
}

function incorrect(){
  $("#result").html("Sorry, you are incorrect.");
}
```